# How to truncate data in OLEDB DESTINATION dynamically in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

My source is flat file and and target is OLEDB Destination.my source and destination both have data.

now my requirement is when iam trying to load source to destination i want truncate existing data in 
destination dynamically and insert new source data. how to implement in SSIS ?

Thanks in advance

PPras'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Acheving the target just go on the **Control flow Task** and take  **execute sql task**  and the right your Truncate script like **Truncate table**  in the Execute Sql task and then connect this to your Data Flow task. From doing this you can achieve[image] your goal. If have you face any Issue then share here

Comment: Thanks its working correctly.now my question is when flat file have  empty that time no need to truncate my destination keep it as same. this correctly working when flat file having data

Comment: For Achieving if file is blank the size of file was zero kb or you can use a script task and read the record count based on the count you can set a variable(@Record_Count). Based on the variable use constraint if the @Record_count >0 then truncate the table and if the@Record_Cunt=0 then don't truncate.

Comment: IF you have a database background if you are not comfortable in the script task. then  first of truncate the table and store the record into Table some where else. in Data flow task use row_count task and through this you can get the row count and update the rowcount in the variable. use constraint after the data flow task and if rowcount is 0 then move date from the temp table to main table. if rowcount is greater than 0 then truncate that temp table.